# Ubuntu live USB can't see internal drive on Macbook Air (early 2015)

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, macbook

I created a bootable USB of 15.10 64 bit and booted my Macbook off it ok but when I tried to do an install the only install location was the USB.

`blkid` and `lsblk` both show only `/dev/sda` (my USB) and `loop0`.

Is there anything I can do to get the drive to show up or is this a bug with Ubuntu?

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -F -A2 -e SATA -e IDE
DeviceName: SATA
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:011a]
Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore

$ sudo dmesg | grep -iEe '\] (ahci|ata|scsi|sd\>)'
[    0.216071] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    8.682654] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[    9.681693] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    9.682106] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    9.903511] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 62533296 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[    9.903762] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    9.903765] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[    9.903978] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    9.906286] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   72.122088] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   73.122897] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[   73.123546] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   73.123953] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 7987200 512-byte logical blocks: (4.08 GB/3.80 GiB)
[   73.124612] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   73.124615] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[   73.125425] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   73.131575] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that we know the storage adapter driver name, what's the output of `sudo dmesg | grep bdw`?

Comment: You could also try the [pre-release version of Ubuntu 16.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/daily-live/current/) and see if the newer kernel changes anything.

Comment: That command has no output. I will try 16.04 now

Comment: Still no improvement with 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this problem myself and I have found that the possible 
cause is the MacBook NVMe SSD is not found because Apple gave it an 
incorrect PCI Class ID.

There is a patch available see link below :

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105621

kernel 4.4 should have the patch applied already so in theory if you
could have a linux installer usb disk with updated 4.4 kernel
it should be possible to install linux on the SSD.

Another option is to apply the patch on an older kernel and install from there

I havent tried this myself yet as i have no experience with patching.

Comment: This is perfect! If ubuntu 16.04 comes out without linux 4.4 will there be any way for me to make a live usb with a newer kernel?

Comment: I read somewhere that 16.04 will probably have 4.4 when it is released. **Ubuntu Kernel Team announced plans for moving to Linux kernel 4.4 for the final release of the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) operating system.**  see : http://linux.slashdot.org/story/15/11/26/1920204/ubuntu-1604-lts-will-ship-with-linux-kernel-44-lts

Comment: Tested the latest beta for 16.04 and it works now. Wifi is still not detected but thats another topic